# ionic.bundle.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following error after taking a picture using the *cordova-plugin-camera* version 1.2.0 plugin on a *SM-G386F* device running *Android 4.2.2*.

My ionic version is *1.1.0*

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at Object.jqLite.addClass (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46098:56)
    at Object.beforeStart (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:40117:17)
    at triggerAnimationStart (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39950:28)
    at runNextTask (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37511:5)
    at nextTick (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37495:7)
    at scheduler (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37466:5)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39942:15
    at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39923:9
    at Scope. (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24560:36)
```

Any help would be very appreciated, as I have no idea how to fix that!

Thanks a lot in advance to anybody willing to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue before.Then i just followed this [tutorial](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/).I got output

**`1.Capture image`**

First add the Camera plugin using the command

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="takePhoto()">Capture</button>
<li ng-repeat="i in myImage">
    <img ng-src="{{baseURL+i}}">
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 75,
        targetWidth: 320,
        targetHeight: 320,
        destinationType: 0,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = imageData;
        $scope.myImage.push($scope.imgURI);
        $scope.$apply();

    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

};
```

**`2.Save photo after capture`**

If you want to save this photo in your storage.Please add file plugin also,

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            cameraDirection: 1,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
            $scope.imgURI = imagePath;
            //Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
            var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            //Create a new name for the photo
            var d = new Date(),
                n = d.getTime(),
                newFileName = n + ".jpg";
            //Move the file to permanent storage
            $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.tempDirectory, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
                //success.nativeURL will contain the path to the photo in permanent storage, do whatever you wish with it, e.g:
                //createPhoto(success.nativeURL);

            }, function(error) {
                //an error occured
            });

        }, function(error) {
            //An error occured
        });
    }
};
```

If you have any doubt.Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Muhsin!I'll try it and send it to my user so he can try out. I'll let you know :)

Comment: @Pierre :Glad to help you.If you have any doubt.Please ask me

Comment: @Pierre:Glad to help you